# What happened to Vpro KVM?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-core-i5, intel-amt, vpro

I bought an intel i5 12400 and an Asus Pro Q670M-C-CSM (vpro enterprise ready )for the AMT kvm.
I used the KVM and it worked fine but after I updated the bios ( ME framework included) the kvm option dissaperead.
Did they just dropped it for my cpu?
Is there any workaround (can't rollback ME version)?
I'd really want to know cause I've bought 4 of them and unfrotunatly updated every single one of them...

Comment: @John didn't they just say they're missing the IP KVM feature that AMT/Vpro has

Comment: Why can't you install the previous bios and where did you get the new one ? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I can rollback the bios, the ME framework though stays with the latest version.

Comment: What exactly is your motherboard and what exactly did you install? Please Edit your post to add these details.

Comment: @harrymc well I edited the mobo name in but aside from that there is really nothing else , I didn't install anything I am talking about the intel AMT kvm.